# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method X on channel plugins.flutter.io/Y)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, mobile

I have migrated my flutter project to null safety by following the steps [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide).

Ever since then, I am facing this error below every now and then for multiple packages.

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
```

The above is of `shared_preferences`, but a similar error is thrown for `path_provider`, `firebase_analytics`.

Here is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
name: news_app
description: A news app

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.10+22

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.1
  http: ^0.13.4
  webview_flutter: ^2.8.0
  firebase_core: ^1.10.6
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.4
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.8.4
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.8.0
  flutter_html: ^2.1.5
  page_view_indicators: ^2.0.0
  splashscreen: ^1.3.5
  intl: ^0.17.0
  jiffy: ^5.0.0
  dio: ^4.0.4
  dio_http_cache: ^0.3.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  share: ^2.0.4
  sqflite: ^2.0.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  timeago: ^3.1.0
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  flutter_tts: ^3.3.2
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.4
  firebase_analytics: ^9.0.4
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.1.5
  chewie: ^1.2.2
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  webview_flutter_plus: ^0.2.3+1
  firebase_admob: ^0.11.2
  scroll_app_bar: ^2.0.0
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/logo.jpg"
  android: true
  ios: true

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: sourcePro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf
    - family: serifPro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/SourceSerifPro-Light.otf
    - family: metaSerifPro
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/FFMetaSerifPro-Light.ttf
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/logo.jpeg
    - assets/tbs_logo_transparent.png
    - assets/logo.png
    - assets/logo.jpg
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Here is the result of `flutter doctor`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS 4.15.0-142-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

I tried the below measures, which I found from other posts, and github issues.

1. I tried switching to different `flutter` channels.
2. Also tried changing the versions of the mentioned packages.
3. Tried deleting cache with `flutter clean`.
4. I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it, still the same.
5. Reinstalled all packages.
6. Restarted Android Studio after invalidating the cache.

None of it worked whatsoever. Before migrating to null safety things were working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you another way instead. Instead of migrating existing project to null safety, create new project (with null safety) and copy `lib` folder from old project. then add the packages (Make sure you have up-to-date versions.) you installed from the old `pubspec.yaml` file to the new `pubspec.yaml` file. (as well as assets and fonts, if any). and if the packages you add require additional integrations for iOS and Android platforms, do them. I stay in the old version of lutter, (ie, non-null-safety) projects in this way I am renewing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I did not think of it. But unfortunately, even in the new project, the same packages are troubling, weird. :-|